# Do any plugins exist for WordPress that allow me to attach extra meta data to images?

Tags: wordpress, metadata, media

From the media section in WordPress, I can see that I can edit

- Title
- Alternate text
- Caption
- Description

I need to add extra data, like shutter speed, location & film.

Short of something like `title: "bla bla", shutterSpeed: "4"` in the description field (and parsing it), is there any plugin that adds this functionality?

It should be easy enough for a laymen to enter data into.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

WordPress will store any EXIF data it can retrieve at point-of-upload into the attachment metadata array (which is serialized in the `postmeta` table under the key `_wp_attachment_metadata`).

You can retrieve this metadata using `wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_ID)`.

To add your own fields to the edit attachment form, check out `get_attachment_fields_to_edit()` in `wp-admin/includes/media.php` (line `1034` as of 3.0).

You can filter `attachment_fields_to_edit`, passing back a structured array like so;

```
function add_my_attachment_field($fields, $post)
{
    $fields['my_field'] = array(
        'label'      => 'My Label',
        'input'      => 'html',
        'html'       => "<input type='text' class='text' name='my_field' value='my_value' />",
        'value'      => 'my_value',
        'helps'      => 'Helper text'
    );
    return $fields;
 }
 add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'add_my_attachment_field', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

NG Gallery can extract metadata from the EXIF data in the image and you have title/description fields as well

Comment: Wordpress by itself will store EXIF data if it exists - not sure whether NG provides some additional editing capabilities?